# iOS: What event is triggered when the keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using JSQMessagesController for a project I'm working on and opened an issue on the Github page, however after some consultation with the author we were not able to resolve the issue.

I have a collectionView which is populated by a list of messages, however when the view is first loaded the top message is cut off from the top of the screen, when the keyboard is shown and dismissed the view displays as intended as demonstrated below:

[image: demonstrates broken message controller]

When the keyboard is shown, an event is obviously fired which revalidates the layout, but what is it?   I have tried the following steps:

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

But this did not remedy the problem - any insight would be appreciated.

EDIT: After testing, the view hierarchy seems to be invalidated when I set the background image for the view:

```
backgroundView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
backgroundView.image = UIImage(named: "background")
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundView, atIndex: 0)
```

Removing these lines gets rid of undesired top-margin, however bringing up the keyboard will still resolve the broken constraint.

Comment: You need to set the UICollectionView top constraint to the Top Layout Guide, so that the View is correctly placed below the UINavigationBar

Comment: Could you provide an answer on how to do that so I can accept it? :)

Comment: Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: Not using a Storyboard or Nib, otherwise I'd set the constraint with interface builder - all of the views constraints are already set via the framework, so I'll have to set it manually in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change insets of the collection view? Something like:

`[self.collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];`

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried below solution..at

-(void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
//(OR)
-(void) viewDidLoad  methods

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: Hey, this works nicely - however it moves my tab bar to the top of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Well, to update the constraints in code, you would have to do something like this:

```
[self.collectionView removeConstraints:self.collectionView.constraints];
NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:self
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               multiplier:1.0f
                               constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint *trailing = [NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:self
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                               multiplier:1.0f
                                constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint *bottom = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                multiplier:1.0f
                                constant:0.f];

[self.collectionView addConstraints:@[top,leading,trailing,bottom]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `delegate` methods of the `UITextField` that you use:

`- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

Comment: I would use this, however it seems the UITextView of the JSQMessageController is a private member, and therefore I cannot invoke it's delegate method manually